# Adding SceneKit Camera node vanishes my main node

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am just starting off with SceneKit and I have some code that renders a cube onto the screen.  It shows up find but as soon as I add a camera node the cube no longer appears on screen.  Given that I'd set the position of the cube's Node to 0,0,0 and the same for the camera, I cannot figure out what is wrong.  I attempted to set the `pointOfView` property of the `SCNView` to the camera node but this did not work.

Here is the code for clarification:

```
func setup() {

      box = SCNBox(width: 30, height: 30, length: 30, chamferRadius: 5)
      shapeNode.geometry = box
      shapeNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z:0)

      mainNode.addChildNode(shapeNode)

      scene.rootNode.addChildNode(mainNode)

      sceneKitView = SCNView(frame:bounds, options:nil)
      sceneKitView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
      sceneKitView.allowsCameraControl = true
      sceneKitView.scene = scene
      sceneKitView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
      addSubview(sceneKitView)

     //      cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
     //      cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 10)
     //      scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
     //      sceneKitView.pointOfView = cameraNode

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if both your camera and cube are at `(0, 0, 0)` then the camera is *inside* the cube and can't see it. You can make your cube's material `doubleSided` so that back-facing triangles are visible, but you probably just want to move your camera at something like `(0, 0, 100)` (a camera's direction of view is along the negative Z axis, and your box has a size of 30).